# How to extract a value from a JSON string by key

Tags: mysql, sql, json, key-value

I have a column which has Json string records. I want to parse the json and fetch the value of a particular key from within the select statement.

Sample JSON

```
{"kofaxDocId":"8ae16f46-c68f-11e5-8105-0e15fb39b661","systemDocType":"Loan Application","requestId":"c770a940-b9f3-4c41-aee6-3e08c1470ec6","docType":"Loan Application","confidence":0.6499999761581421,"engineType":"kofax","completionStatus":"Suggested"}
```

I want my select query to fetch only the value of the key "confidence". I tried using Regex and Substring, but since the json length is not fixed, it doesn't fetch correct values for all the records.

i tried these

```
SELECT substring(extended_metadata, ('"confidence":', extended_metadata ))  FROM documents ;

SELECT json_extract(extended_metadata,'confidence') CONFIDENCE from documents;
```

The Json_extract() isn't supported with my MYSQL version.

Appreciate help.

Comment: What is jour Mysql version ? Can you upgrade it easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL has got support for JSON in version 5.7.7 http://mysqlserverteam.com/json-labs-release-native-json-data-type-and-binary-format/

You have to resolive it purely in mysql then I am afraid you have to treat it as a string and cut the value out of it (just normal string functions or use regular expressions) This is not elegant but it will work

```
CREATE TABLE testjson (`jsonfield` varchar(2000)) ;

INSERT INTO testjson (`jsonfield`) VALUES ('{"kofaxDocId":"8ae16f46-c68f-11e5-8105-0e15fb39b661","systemDocType":"Loan Application","requestId":"c770a940-b9f3-4c41-aee6-3e08c1470ec6","docType":"Loan Application","confidence":0.6499999761581421,"engineType":"kofax","completionStatus":"Suggested"}')  ;


SELECT substring(jsonfield, locate('"confidence":',jsonfield)+13, locate(',"', jsonfield, locate('"confidence":',jsonfield))-locate('"confidence":',jsonfield)-13) as confidence_value
  FROM testjson;
```

This query search for Confidence in your jsondata, then look at the next separator after confidence, and it substract the content between these two index.

Here's a SQL fiddle of the example above: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2edfaf/3/0

Answer (score 0):

I had to alter Kobi's script since the substring would fail if the value was at the end of the JSON file since it was looking for ',"'.  This script will extract a string.

Replace the 15 in the script with the length of the column title.  (i.e = "referred-by":)

Replace "referred-by" with the column title.

```
SELECT  substring(jsonfield, locate('"referred-by":',jsonfield)+15, (locate('"', jsonfield, locate('"referred-by":',jsonfield)+15))-(locate('"referred-by":',jsonfield)+15)) as referredby
```