# Select a specific item in a dict SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

How do i select an item from a dict with sql?
Im inserting on my table the following:

```
{"url":"https://gcphone.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/aaef9495-90dc-48ec-b913-0902f7f8759b.jpg"}
```

But i want to create a trigger that before insert it only inserts:

```
https://gcphone.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/aaef9495-90dc-48ec-b913-0902f7f8759b.jpg
```

How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: What is the type of column?

Comment: it would be a lot simpler if you extracted the url within the application logic from the json data, rather than leaving this to mysql triggers to deal with!

Comment: it's seems to me you will handle json content. if so you can handle it via mysql easily. check you mysql version and documentation on mysql & json handling

Comment: @InsungPark it is varchar type

Comment: `select json_extract('{"url":"https://gcphone.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/aaef9495-90dc-48ec-b913-0902f7f8759b.jpg"}', '$.url');`   After this you should remove the leading, and trailing quotes...

Comment: I thing this question may helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436992/how-to-extract-a-value-from-a-json-string-by-key

Comment: @InsungPark It worked i got mi links correctly. But now how i transfor this to a trigger ? `SELECT substring(image, locate('"url":"',image)+7, locate('"}', image, locate('"url":"',image))-locate('"url":"', image)-7) as image
  FROM insto_instas;`